# Unique sets of angles?

Tags: geometry

Consider shapes composed of isosceles right triangles of a unit size and joined at edges of equal length, with the restriction that any such shape must have a perimeter edge count of n+2, where n is the number of triangles contained in shape.  Furthermore, all flips and rotations of any shape are considered the same shape.  Now create a list of the exterior angles of every vertex in the perimeter of a given shape.  Is the sorted set of angles unique to every shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume the perimeter edge count is the number of segements on the perimeter, even if the segments make up one straight side.  This prevents the formation of large square regions.  No, for $n=7$ take a triangle, attach a square to each short side, then one more triangle on the opposite side of the square.  The list of angles is the same for either orientation of the end triangles.

[image: see below]

Even simpler
[image]

Comment: Thanks. What program did you use to generate those images?

Comment: @jnthn:  I drew them in PowerPoint, saved to JPEG.  By holding down the shift key they are forced to be $90-45-45$

Comment: Yes, segment count is correct.